# Possible tensorflow cholesky_solve inconsistency?

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I am trying to solve a linear system of equations using [tensorflow.cholesky_solve](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#cholesky_solve) and I'm getting some unexpected results.

I wrote a script to compare the output of a very simple linear system with simple matrix inversion a la [tensorflow.matrix_inverse](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#matrix_inverse), the non-cholesky based matrix equation solver [tensorflow.matrix_solve](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#matrix_solve), and `tensorflow.cholesky_solve`.

According to my understanding of the docs I've linked, these three cases should all yield a solution of the identity matrix divided by 2, but this is not the case for `tensorflow.cholesky_solve`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the docs?

```
import tensorflow as tf

I = tf.eye(2, dtype=tf.float32)
X = 2 * tf.eye(2, dtype=tf.float32)
X_inv = tf.matrix_inverse(X)
X_solve = tf.matrix_solve(X, I)
X_chol_solve = tf.cholesky_solve(tf.cholesky(X), I)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for x in [X_inv, X_solve, X_chol_solve]:
        print('{}:\n{}'.format(x.name, sess.run(x)))
        print
```

yielding output:

```
MatrixInverse:0:
[[ 0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.5]]

MatrixSolve:0:
[[ 0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.5]]

cholesky_solve/MatrixTriangularSolve_1:0:
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug. Notice how the result doesn't even depend on the `RHS`, unless `RHS = 0`, in which case you get `nan` instead of `0`. Please report it on GitHub.